# Integrating jQuery with Struts2.0.9

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins, struts2

How can I integrating jQuery with Struts 2.0.9? Here I can not upgrade my Struts2 version. I want to leverage jQuery ajax functionality with Struts2. Not able to figure out how can I pass a valuestack object to jQuery.

Comment: I guess the best version of Struts2 Jquery Plugin for Struts2.0.9 would be Struts2-Jquery-Plugin 2.5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use either [struts2-jquery-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/)

Struts2 does not care of you call its action by Normal page submit or by ajax calling using Jquery or any other javascript framework

Once you call you action value-stack and other critical parameters of Struts2 will be available at your disposal.

Still your question is not clear what is your requirements, more details can pour more valuable inputs

Comment: I know about the struts2-jquery-plugin but it is not supporting Struts 2.0.9. It is not possible to me to upgrade struts jars in production.

Answer (score 0):

Though the question has been answered, there are some significant issues when we speak about struts2 jQuery plugin 2.5.0.

1. It is based on jQuery 1.4 which is outdated, multiple issues have been closed from 1.4 to 1.7
2. Multiple browser support issues especially with IE (if you want to have browser compatibility).

I found it much more easy to directly use jQuery with Struts2. As mentioned, calling via Ajax or non ajax has doesnt make any difference to Struts2 framework, request is handled in the same way.

If you want to use Struts2 jQuery Plugin you can either work on the source code and upgrade the jQuery to 1.7 and accordingly change newer API.